# Getting text of each row in a table, matching these texts in another table and creating a new table containing all matches

Tags: r, for-loop, match

Let me explain this question with an example. I have two data frames:

```
  df1 <- data.frame(Gene=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 Description=c("ribonuclease HII", "Leucyl-tRNA synthetase", "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195", "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)", "PAS domain S-box protein", "ribonuclease HII", "Isoleucyl-tRNA synthetase", "Succinyl-CoA ligase"),
                 Species=c("aa", "bb","aa","cc","ee","ff","aa","dd"),
                 Number1= c(1,0,3,20,99,100,31,123),
                 Number2 =c(1000, 12636,12,455,231,454,123,1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   > df1
  Gene                                       Description Species Number1 Number2
1    1                                  ribonuclease HII      aa       1    1000
2    2                            Leucyl-tRNA synthetase      bb       0   12636
3    3 Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195      aa       3      12
4    4             Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)      cc      20     455
5    5                          PAS domain S-box protein      ee      99     231
6    6                                  ribonuclease HII      ff     100     454
7    7                         Isoleucyl-tRNA synthetase      aa      31     123
8    8                               Succinyl-CoA ligase      dd     123       1
```

And df2 which contains interested gene names:

```
 df2 <- data.frame(Description=c("ribonuclease HII", "Leucyl-tRNA synthetase", "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    > df2
                            Description
1                      ribonuclease HII
2                Leucyl-tRNA synthetase
3 Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)
```

Summary of my question:

Here I would like to match the text in the each row of df2 to df1 and put them to a new table. For example, the function will search "ribonuclease HII" in df1 and get all the rows containing this text. Then it will check for the next row of df2 (Leucyl-tRNA synthetase) in df1 and so on... After finishing all the searches, it will put them together. The expected output should be a table containing following rows:

```
   > df1
  Gene                                       Description Species Number1 Number2
1    1                                  ribonuclease HII      aa       1    1000
2    6                                  ribonuclease HII      ff     100     454
3    2                            Leucyl-tRNA synthetase      bb       0   12636
4    3 Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195      aa       3      12
5    4             Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)      cc      20     455
```

I have tried with grep function in a for loop, but couldn't do it successfully. Here there is a tricky part: when searching for "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)", It should also catch "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195". However, when the function searches for "Leucyl-tRNA synthetase", it shouldn't take "Iso**leucyl-tRNA synthetase**" which contains the same wording as "Leucyl-tRNA synthetase".

Thanks in advance. I am also open to your suggestions for the title and the edits in the text!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl()` to get your desired results. First, create a search pattern (this does not have word boundaries (`"\\b"`) so it will just look for match). Then escape all meta-characters except for `"|"` using `gsub()`, and then use `grepl()` to subset the rows in `df1`:

```
new_pat <-paste0(df2$Description, collapse = "|")
new_pat <- gsub("([][{}().+*^$\\?])", "\\\\\\1", new_pat)

df1[grepl(new_pat, df1$Description), ]
  Gene                                       Description Species Number1 Number2
1    1                                  ribonuclease HII      aa       1    1000
2    2                            Leucyl-tRNA synthetase      bb       0   12636
3    3 Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195      aa       3      12
4    4             Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)      cc      20     455
6    6                                  ribonuclease HII      ff     100     454
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lejf_join` function from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(Gene=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  Description=c("ribonuclease HII", "Leucyl-tRNA synthetase", "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195", "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)", "PAS domain S-box protein", "ribonuclease HII", "Isoleucyl-tRNA synthetase", "Succinyl-CoA ligase"),
                  Species=c("aa", "bb","aa","cc","ee","ff","aa","dd"),
                  Number1= c(1,0,3,20,99,100,31,123),
                  Number2 =c(1000, 12636,12,455,231,454,123,1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Description=c("ribonuclease HII", "Leucyl-tRNA synthetase","Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195", "Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

left_join(df2, df1, by = "Description") %>% select(Gene, everything())
```

The last line prints what you need:

```
  Gene                                       Description Species Number1 Number2
1    1                                  ribonuclease HII      aa       1    1000
2    6                                  ribonuclease HII      ff     100     454
3    2                            Leucyl-tRNA synthetase      bb       0   12636
4    3 Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19) 17855:19195      aa       3      12
5    4             Arginyl-tRNA synthetase (EC 6.1.1.19)      cc      20     455
```

Good luck!